# Weird issue during parsing a path in Python

Tags: python, parsing

Given this variables:

```
cardIP="00.00.00.00"
dir="D:\\TestingScript"
mainScriptPath='"\\\\XX\\XX\\XX\\Testing\\SNMP Tests\\Python Script\\MainScript.py"'
```

When using `subprocess.call("cmd /c "+mainScriptPath+" "+dir+" "+cardIP)` and `print(mainScriptPath+" "+dir+" "+cardIP)` I get this:

```
 "\\XX\XX\XX\Testing\SNMP Tests\Python Script\MainScript.py"  D:\TestingScript  00.00.00.00
```

which is what I wanted, OK.

But now, I want the 'dir' variable to be also inside "" because I am going to use dir names with spaces.
So, I do the same thing I did with 'mainScriptPath':

```
cardIP="00.00.00.00"
dir='"D:\\Testing Script"'
mainScriptPath='"\\XX\\XX\\XX\\Testing\\SNMP Tests\\Python Script\\MainScript.py"'
```

But now, when I'm doing `print(mainScriptPath+" "+dir+" "+cardIP)` I get:

```
"\\XX\XX\XX\Testing\SNMP Tests\Python Script\MainScript.py"  "D:\Testing Script"  00.00.00.00
```

Which is great, but when executed in `subprocess.call("cmd /c "+mainScriptPath+" "+dir+" "+cardIP)` there is a failure with 'mainScriptPath' variable:

```
 '\\XX\XX\XX\Testing\SNMP' is not recognized as an internal or external command...
```

It doesn't make sense to me.
Why does it fail?

In addition, I tried also:

```
dir="\""+"D:\\Testing Script"+"\""
```

Which in 'print' acts well but in 'subprocess.call' raise the same problem.

(Windows XP, Python3.3)

Comment: What happens when you type the same command at the commandline?

Comment: Please use Pythonic string expansion, like `"%s %s" % (arg1, arg2)` or   `"{1} {2}".format(...)`. This is not javascript, there's almost never a good reason at add strings with a `+`.

Comment: I edited this post. please notice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper string formatting, use single quotes for the formatting string and simply include the quotes:

```
subprocess.call('cmd /c "{}" "{}" "{}"'.format(mainScriptPath, dir, cardIP))
```

The alternative is to pass in a *list* of arguments and have Python take care of quoting for you:

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', mainScriptPath, dir, cardIP])
```

When the first argument to `.call()` is a list, Python uses the process described under the section [Converting an argument sequence to a string on Windows](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence).

> On Windows, an *args* sequence is converted to a string that can be
>   parsed using the following rules (which correspond to the rules used
>   by the MS C runtime):
>
> 1. Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a space or a tab.
> 2. A string surrounded by double quotation marks is interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space contained within. A quoted
>      string can be embedded in an argument.
> 3. A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark.
> 4. Backslashes are interpreted literally, unless they immediately precede a double quotation mark.
> 5. If backslashes immediately precede a double quotation mark, every pair of backslashes is interpreted as a literal backslash. If the
>      number of backslashes is odd, the last backslash escapes the next
>      double quotation mark as described in rule 3.

This means that passing in your arguments as a sequence makes Python worry about all the nitty gritty details of escaping your arguments properly, including handling embedded backslashes and double quotes.

Comment: If Im using one of this ways, how should I define the 'mainScriptPath, dir' variables? with "'", with "\"" or not at all?

Comment: @user2162550: No quoting needed in that case, let Python handle those for you.

Comment: @user2162550: Then the problem lies with the `MainScript.py` that you are invoking. The `subprocess` call is doing everything it can to pass the paths properly quoted. In that script, what does `print sys.argv` tell you was passed in?

Comment: @user2162550: You *did* remove the quotes from `mainScriptPath`, right?

Comment: @user2162550: You'll have to show the exact values of your variables and the error message.